# C++ template that differentiates static arrays, pointers and structs

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, templates, struct

Currently I have a template function that compiler can deduce `TI` for static arrays and pointers (of common types) as arguments:

```cpp
template<typename TI, typename TO>
inline void foo(const TI a[4], TO b[][3]) { /* works for static arrays and pointers */ }
```

However, now I need to have the same function for a struct type with 4 members `x`, `y`, `z` and `w`, representing the same 4 items on old array-type.

But I can't do this:

```cpp
template<typename TI, typename TO>
inline void foo(const TI a[4], TO b[][3]) { /* static arrays and pointer */ }


template<typename TI, typename TO>
inline void foo(const TI a, TO b[][3]) { /* structs */ }
```

If I specify an extra parameter `size` for the first function, then pointers arguments end up on below function, and compiler raises an error since the pointers does not have the required struct members.

I can't specialize for a specific type of struct, since we now use several types (varying internal members type's `double`, `float`, `int`, etc.)

---

MRE:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
 
template <typename TI, typename TO>
inline
void foo(const TI q[4], TO a[][3])
{
    std::cout << "Method 1\n";
    a[0][0] = a[0][1] = a[0][2] = q[0] + q[1];
    a[1][0] = a[1][1] = a[1][2] = q[1] + q[2];
    a[2][0] = a[2][1] = a[2][2] = q[2] + q[3];
}
 
template <class QT, typename TO>
inline
void foo(const QT q, TO a[][3])
{
    std::cout << "Method 2\n";
    a[0][0] = a[0][1] = a[0][2] = q.x + q.y;
    a[1][0] = a[1][1] = a[1][2] = q.y + q.z;
    a[2][0] = a[2][1] = a[2][2] = q.z + q.w;
}
 
typedef struct {
    float x, y, z, w;
} float4;
 
int main() {
 
    float q1[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    float4 q2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    float *q3 = new float[4];
    q3[0] = 1; q3[1] = 2; q3[2] = 3; q3[3] = 4;
    
    float a[3][3], b[3][3], c[3][3];
    
    foo(q1, a);
    foo(q2, b);
    foo(q3, c);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                assert(a[i][j] == b[i][j]);
                assert(b[i][j] == c[i][j]);
            }
}
```

---

Compiler Error:

```
teste.cpp:19:36: error: member reference base type 'float *const' is not a structure or
      union
    a[0][0] = a[0][1] = a[0][2] = q.x + q.y;
                                  ~^~
teste.cpp:37:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'foo<float *, float>' requested here
    foo(q1, a);
    ^
teste.cpp:20:36: error: member reference base type 'float *const' is not a structure or
      union
    a[1][0] = a[1][1] = a[1][2] = q.y + q.z;
                                  ~^~
teste.cpp:21:36: error: member reference base type 'float *const' is not a structure or
      union
    a[2][0] = a[2][1] = a[2][2] = q.z + q.w;
                                  ~^~
3 errors generated.
```

Comment: please include a [mcve] and the compiler error.

Comment: For an actual array, you could create an overload that takes a reference to an array, as in `template<typename TI, size_t SIZE> void function(TI (&a)[SIZE])`

Comment: in relation to the previous comment: you know that when your comment says `/* arrays and pointer */` you actually have a pointer not an array? Arrays cannot be passed by value

Comment: Update: added MRE

Comment: Update: added compiler error

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried it, but then the compilation fails for common pointers, trying to use the second specialization instead of the first one

Comment: One overload for pointers, one for arrays?

Comment: @idclev463035818 when I say arrays I'm refering to C/C++ static arrays. I know that they are not passed by value. However as we can specify its size on argument, we can say that compiler can spot differences between them and raw pointers at some compilation level.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried it too: If a specialization for pointers is found, it claims that `more than one instance of overloaded function "foo" matches the argument list` for static arrays

Comment: @648trindade When you do `float *q3 = new float[4];` and pass `q3` to the function, there's no way the function can now how many `float`s you've allocated memory for - if you don't supply that as a separate argument.

Comment: Update: Added MRE inside question body

Comment: @TedLyngmo before the need for inclusion of support of these struct-types, compiler could cast `TI*` into  `TI[4]`. However now it gets confused since we have to use a new type that is not a pointer nor a explicit sized-array

Comment: not sure if you understand, when you declare a fucntion like this: `void foo(int x[5]) { }` then actually there is no array, it is equivalent to `void foo(int * x)`. The reason it works for pointers and static arrays is that static arrays can decay to pointers to their first element. Also note that the information on size is completely lost. You can pass an array of size 42 to `foo` without getting a compiler error

Comment: @648trindade The `T1` is then just a pointer, not a array.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/qT9Md4

Comment: @MarekR awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to use type traits available as from C++11

You can declare your function dedicated for structures as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class QT, typename TO, std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<QT>::value, int> = 0>
inline
void foo(const QT q, TO a[][3])
{
    std::cout << "Method 2\n";
    a[0][0] = a[0][1] = a[0][2] = q.x + q.y;
    a[1][0] = a[1][1] = a[1][2] = q.y + q.z;
    a[2][0] = a[2][1] = a[2][2] = q.z + q.w;
}
```

That would let compiler select this template for structures and classes but not for others. This is so called SFINAE technique.